# How may Win10 20H2 be forced to update to only 21H1 and NOT to 21H2?

Tags: windows-10

As you are aware, Win10 20H2's support tenure ends in May.
Usually, an upgrade to the most recent version of Windows 10 is required. Therefore, Win10 21H2.I would rather upgrade to only Windows 10 21H1.
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Support for 20H2 ended over a year ago. Are you also aware by staying on 21H2 you won’t receive any security cumulative updates? Is there a reason you don’t want to update to 21H2 even though it’s installed through an enablement package? To receive 21H1 instead of 21H2 you would have to upgrade with the 22H1 ISO. Additionally, 22H2 has actually already been released.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the target feature update version as 21H1, run the following
`.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"ProductVersion"="Windows 10"
"TargetReleaseVersion"=dword:00000001
"TargetReleaseVersionInfo"="21H1"
```

---

Alternatively, you may open the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
and navigate to this location:

*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Windows Update for Business*

Double-click on "Select the target Feature Update version", click Enabled,
and set the two fields to `Windows 10` and `21H1` respectively.